# How can I make part of the title in cventry non-bold?

Tags: xetex, moderncv

I am trying to modify part of the title of the `\cventry` of the moderncv package so that it won't be bold (pleas see the part in red).

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Here's an MWE

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{green}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.77]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

% personal data
\name{Tran Thai Duc Hieu}{}
\title{18 years, Ho Chi Minh City}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Ly Thai To Street}{District 3}{Ho CHi Minh City}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{090.137.8414}                   % optional, , remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{trthduchieu@gmail.com}                               %  remove / comment the line if not wanted

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{Nov 00 - Dec 04}{Complete PhD Degree}{Beer University}{Brewery}{Max}{}
\cventry{2019--NOW}{Bachelor}{Information Technology}{University of Sciences}
{\textit{District 5}}{}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following replacement for the `cventry` line:

```
\cventry{Nov 00 - Dec 04}{{\normalfont Complete} PhD Degree}{Beer University}{Brewery}{Max}{}
```